# Как делать задание А16-А17 Егэ по русскому языку?

Tags: егэ

Здравствуйте!

Не понимаю А17. А16 раз на раз не приходиться.

Как их делать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Напомните, о чеи они?

Comment: Самостоятельно?

Answer (score 2):

Если это то, о чем был вопрос, то для выполнения А-16 надо выучить спряжения глагола и суффиксы причастий от них зависящие; для выполнения А-17 - знать правописание суффиксов.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду тесты егэ 2014, то что именно вам не ясно? Вот вопросы: А16)В каком ряду в обоих словах на месте пропуска пишется буква И?
1) произнос..шь, преобразу..мый
2) относ..шься, распущ..нный
3) засмотр..шься, замет..вший
4) перекин..шь, сломл..нный 
А17)В каком варианте ответа правильно указаны все слова, где пропущена
буква Е?
А. никел..вый
Б. достра..вать
В. приветл..во
Г. оскуд..вать

1) А, Б, Г
2) А, Б, В
3) В, Г
4) А, Г

Вас эти задание интересуют?

Но мы не экстрасенсы. А вопрос  надо формулировать четче.

Comment: Иметь в виду* =/